# Control div of an asp page using master and vary div dynamically

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have created an asp page with a master page and it has one div element which is variable. That is when a user clicks on one link of navigation panel (which is in master page) the div element is changed using jQuery.

And that div content I have written in separate html files. So in short I load a html file in a div  when a user clicks on navigation panel, such that the whole page is not refreshed but only the div part.

One such div stores data in the database. The insertion is working fine. Now when insertion is completed, I want to display a message in same  that records was inserted successfully (do this from codebeind). How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what code you've tried, or really what your attempting to do.  You can push data to your client a couple of ways:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
      this.GetType(), @"NameOfFunction", @"alert('Message');");
```

That will actually call Javascript from the code behind, obviously this approach has some drawbacks.  Troubleshooting isn't always clear, as where the message is deriving from isn't blatantly obvious.

Secondly, would be the all mighty `$.ajax`.  With this approach you can actually abstract a bit, which is nice.  You'll end up with a value that comes back for instance:

```
// Build our object with a Clean Constructor:
function BuildOrder(Product, Quantity, Price) {
     var item = null;
     if(Product & Quantity & Price) {
          Product: Product,
          Quantity: Quantity,
          Price: Price
          };
}
```

That is our builder, then we build our `object`.

```
var order = new Array();
order.push(BuildOrder(product, quantity, price));
convertedOrder = JSON.stringify(order);
```

Then you have a `JSON` value which is basically a giant `string` to pass from the Client to the Server.  Then you build your `Ajax`.

```
        $.ajax({
            url: '<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/Services/Credit.aspx") %>',
            data: { Order: convertedOrder },
            type: 'POST',

            success: function (order) {
                var result = JSON.parse(order);
                $("#<%= txtTax.ClientID %>").val('$' + result[0].Tax).change();
                $("#lblTotal").text('$' + result[0].Total);
            },

            failure: function () {
                alert('There was an error in retrieving the total and tax, please continue inputting for it to automatically refresh.');
            }
        });
    }
```

Then on the server you just use the `JavaScriptSerializer` to deserialize and serialize back after you iterate through it.  The `success` and `failure` will be returned so it does something.